# Replacing words while processing documents before tokenize in Rapidminer

Tags: rapidminer

I have set of documents and would like to replace some of the word sets  with a single word before tokenize.

ex. "follow up" --> follow-up,

```
 "Set up" --> Setup and 

  "with out" --> without
```

I tried using Replace(dictionary) by loading a csv file with the potential words. But can't tokenize after.

[image]

How do I do this?

Thanks,

Aji

Comment: Have you ever used the "Execute Script" operator before "Tokenize" ?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at Stem (Dictionary). this can be missused to do your trick.

Cheers,
Martin

Comment: Thanks Martin. unfortunately STEM(Dictionary) is not working for me.  I tried with one line text and is not working. Ex. textfile : "This is  interesting",  dictionary fascinating:interesting , result "this is interesting". Not sure why its not working